# binding in Repeater control with restricted records and ohter data on background process from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have repeater control under the marquee tag. I want to bind only 10 record first from database and other data on background process so user can not fill that data is loading and my page also get load fast.

As marquee pass 10 records then next 10 records is loaded and so on. Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a marquee tag to display 10 records at a time.  It could be distracting to the user.  What about pagination?  Then the next 10 records wouldn't load unless the user requested them

[Pagination with repeater control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31819/Pagination-with-Repeater-Control)

Comment: it is list of client that i want to show to visitor, so i want to show in marquee and i want to show huge list from database. its also contain image so i don't want to load whole data which excessively load to my page that will take too much time.